# Panda Dataframe with different dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have CSV files, the first column is datetime, and the number of columns vary in each file (from 50 columns to 200 columns). Since there are blanks/NaNs in some of the columns, I get the warning "DtypeWarning: Columns (1,2,3,4,...) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False."
I was wondering what's the best solution to either specify dtype but with a varying number of columns or remove those rows only when reading that column?

Comment: If you have float columns with missing values, part of the issue could be that the default N/A values are not catching all of the N/A flags in the data (e.g. `#NA`, `n.a.`, etc. will result in string values, not `np.nan`). See the `na_values` and `keep_default_na` arguments to [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). If the problem really is dtype specification, then... yeah you have your work cut out for you in terms of specifying variable column types for each file. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Since my column names are changing for each file, I ended up using pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0, nrows=0).columns.tolist() to get the column names first and then use indexes to specify the data types for each column. I also used keep_default_na options, thanks for mentioning that. I had not remembered it before you mentioned it.